# Is there a way to cancel or manually end manipulate?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

So, I'm in the battle arena on disc 1. I had my green materia broken, so when the arena brought out [Zemzelett](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Zemzelett_(Final_Fantasy_VII)), I thought it would be the perfect chance for a free heal, as I knew I could manipulate him and use white wind on Cloud.

**This was a bad idea.**

Unfortunately, Zemzelett only has two actions in his list. Both of which require MP - more MP than he has after using white wind. As such, either action results in a message that his skill power is used up.  Because the battle arena is solo, and Cloud is manipulating the Zemzelett, and the Zemzelett has no actionable commands, I think I may be stuck. I was hoping it would time out or after so many commands the manipulate would end, but no luck so far.

Is there any way to manually end manipulate, or otherwise end it if I'm unable to attack the manipulated enemy?

Comment: Well sounds like you've to load the last save.. can't find a way to stop manipulating without beeing attacked

Comment: Fortunately, escape is still an option to avoid losing BP. Learned my lesson this time.

Comment: Even though this was your question, you can still post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like there was no method of ending the manipulate action in this situation. As such, the best solution was to forfeit the BPs by escaping the battle.